# Getting started using Microsoft Academic Graph API

Tags: web-services, azure, azure-cognitive-services, academic-graph

I am trying to run some queries on Microsoft Academic Graph using [their API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/academic-knowledge/home). I cannot figure out what to use for the `Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key`. (I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40867834/where-to-find-my-ocp-apim-subscription-key-in-windows-azure) and it did not help.) When I try to run queries I get the following message (401: access denied): `Access denied due to invalid subscription key. Make sure you are subscribed to an API you are trying to call and provide the right key.`. This happens either using curl on the command line:

```
curl -v -X GET "https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com\
/academic/v1.0/evaluate?\
expr=stochastic&model=latest&count=10&offset=0&attributes=Id" \
-H "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
```

or using the [API testing console](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/56332331778daf02acc0a50b/operations/565d9001ca73072048922d97/console).

So what am I using for the `Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key`? (Not a lot of Xs!) I've tried two things. First, I've tried using the key that you can get by going to https://labs.cognitive.microsoft.com/en-us/project-academic-knowledge and clicking on the subscribe link (either Key 1 or Key 2).

Second, I've tried using a key generated by going to the [cognitive services on my azure portal](https://portal.azure.com/#blade/HubsExtension/BrowseResourceBlade/resourceType/Microsoft.CognitiveServices%2Faccounts), and trying to create a subscription to a suitable service. However, nothing that I can see matches the Academic Search API that I want to use, so I used a generic bing search subscription.

Neither of these grants me access to the API. What am I missing?

**EDIT:**

After first response by @ali-heikal, I tried going to here: https://dev.labs.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/56332331778daf02acc0a50b/operations/5951f78363b4fb31286b8ef4/console. A red warning box appears at top of page: `You are not subscribed to this API and will get a '401 Access Denied' response. To subscribe, go to the Products page and click on the desired product containing this API.`. If I go to the Products page, and go on to the [Project Academic Knowledge - Preview](https://dev.labs.cognitive.microsoft.com/products/5636d970e597ed0690ac1b3f) page, I am offered the chance to subscribe. Clicking subscribe takes me to a generic MS sign in (I am signed in, choose that account), I am taken to a page which says:

> We're unable to complete your request
>   Microsoft account is experiencing technical problems. Please try again later.

So this does not work for me. Where is it documented that I should use this endpoint? Can someone provide further instructions on how to use it?

**EDIT2:**

There is this answer which describes using a different endpoint: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49318405/54557. However, changing my curl request to use this does not work (with same Access denied error).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong endpoint, since you're using the Preview API, then you should use the [Preview endpoint](https://dev.labs.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/56332331778daf02acc0a50b/operations/5951f78363b4fb31286b8ef4/console) as well.

It should work if you follow those steps:

- Regenerate a key from [here](https://labs.cognitive.microsoft.com/en-us/project-academic-knowledge) (do not use an old key this time) and confirm by clicking the **Yes, regenerate this key** button
- Open the **Testing Console** from [here](https://dev.labs.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/56332331778daf02acc0a50b/operations/5951f78363b4fb31286b8ef4/console)
- Insert the key you just generated into the **Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key** field
- Insert the following into the **Request body** field: `expr=Composite(AA.AuN=='ali heikal')&count=2&attributes=Ti,Y,CC,AA.AuN,AA.AuId`
- Click the `Send` button

Check the Entity Attributes documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/academic-knowledge/authorentityattributes) to understand the attributes I included following the Evaluate Method documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/academic-knowledge/evaluatemethod)

I think the problem is that you are using an old key with the wrong endpoint and attribute values.

Comment: Thank you for the clear instructions, they worked as you said they should. They work using `curl` as well:

`curl -v -X GET "https://api.labs.cognitive.microsoft.com/academic/v1.0/evaluate?expr=Composite(AA.AuN=='ali%20heikal')&count=2&attributes=Ti,Y,CC,AA.AuN,AA.AuId" -H "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX`